# How to kill a writer's block?

Tags: writers-block

It's been a year now since I have this. I can't write and think. Any suggestions, advice and tips?

Comment: I'm with @LaurenIpsum, there are a lot of posts here and he did not look through. I vote to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @JPChapleau finding duplicates is a service to both the OP (look, answers already!) and the community.

Answer (score 0):

Sit down and write. One of the best techniques I was ever taught was to simply sit down and write the first thing that comes into your head. Start and don't stop. What arrives on the page may turn out to be gibberish, but just keep going, don't pause to do anything, especially not to edit. Set a limit of 10 or 20 minutes and just keep writing the entire time. You may find that you can gleam some idea from what you've got, or you may just have a page of nonsense. But you've started. Then do it again tomorrow :)